# How to get Maximum Likelihood Estimates

Tags: r, mle

I am following the paper of [C. Binder](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/muse.union.edu/dist/5/317/files/2015/01/33-Carola-Binder-2015-inflation-uncertainty.pdf) for inflation expectations. I have bi-monthly data from 2012 to 2022 (64 waves of data) and for each time period I have to estimate 5 parameters  using the distribution function given in this paper. I am using `nlm` function for optimization but the problem is that `nlm` performs perfectly fine for some waves but does not optimize the parameters for the given likelihood function and produces `NaNs` . For those waves which gives error, I have also tried `nlminb` and `optim` functions. But they also fail to perform optimization. Below is the code that I have written for optimization:

```
IE<- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,64,5)) %>% setNames(c('mu_l','sd_l','mu_h','sd_h','lambda'))
for (i in 1:64){
  IE[i,1]<-mean(df$jk[df$wave==i])
  IE[i,2]<-sd(df$jk[df$wave==i])
  IE[i,3]<-mean(df$jk[df$wave==i])
  IE[i,4]<-sd(df$jk[df$wave==i])
  IE[i,5]<-sum(df$jk[df$wave==i]%%10==0)/length(df$jk[df$wave==i])
}
#empty matrix for final estimates for parameters
FE<- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,64,6)) %>% setNames(c('mu_l','sd_l','mu_h','sd_h','lambda','negloglike'))

for(i in 1:64){
  negloglike<- function(x){
    mu_l<-x[1]
    sd_l<-x[2]
    mu_h<-x[3]
    sd_h<-x[4]
    lambda<-x[5]
    y<- seq(min(df$jk[df$wave==i]),max(df$jk[df$wave==i]), 1) #list of values for phi_l
    y1<- seq(min(df$jk[df$wave==i]),max(df$jk[df$wave==i]), 10) #list of values for phi_h
    phi_h<- pnorm(y1+5,mu_h,sd_h)-pnorm(y1-5,mu_h,sd_h)  #calculating phi_h
    phi_h<- as.data.frame(cbind(y1,phi_h))%>%setNames(c('y','phi_h')) #calculating phi_h
    phi_l<- as.data.frame(cbind(y,pnorm(y+0.5,mu_l,sd_l)-pnorm(y-0.5,mu_l,sd_l))) %>% 
      setNames(c('y','phi_l'))                            #calculating Phi_l
    phi<-left_join(phi_l,phi_h) %>%replace(is.na(.),0)  #combining Phi_h and phi_l in one df
    wave<- as.data.frame(df$jk[df$wave==i])%>%setNames('y')  #getting values of the IE from given wave
    phi<-left_join(wave,phi)                                    #matching wave values with their respective phi values
    (-sum(log((lambda*(phi$phi_h-phi$phi_l))+phi$phi_l))) #getting negative log likelihood function value
  }
  out<-nlm(negloglike,p=as.numeric(IE[i,])) #applying iteration to get MLE estimates of parameter
  FE[i,]<- c(out[[2]],out[[1]])  # sending the parameter values to the FE table made above
```

I am really stuck on this. can someone please help me out. If any further information is required please ask in comments.

Edit: date for wave 18 which is giving error. Below is `dput()` output

```
c(105, 200, 150, 105, 110, 105, 110, 150, 120, 120, 130, 140, 
110, 110, 105, 115, 125, 110, 105, 125, 110, 110, 125, 110, 150, 
150, 200, 115, 105, 105, 105, 105, 110, 125, 110, 110, 105, 175, 
120, 150, 120, 130, 120, 125, 115, 125, 115, 115, 110, 115, 170, 
110, 120, 105, 120, 110, 105, 120, 120, 103, 110, 107, 115, 150, 
140, 150, 125, 200, 115, 113, 120, 110, 120, 115, 125, 150, 120, 
110, 125, 150, 175, 150, 105, 103, 200, 130, 108, 150, 200, 105, 
105, 108, 105, 120, 110, 120, 200, 115, 115, 105, 95, 107, 200, 
120, 150, 120, 110, 115, 140, 125, 102, 150, 120, 105, 110, 105, 
105, 102, 110, 130, 120, 101, 105, 108, 110, 120, 300, 125, 130, 
150, 150, 105, 125, 200, 150, 160, 150, 110, 150, 120, 120, 150, 
200, 140, 95, 130, 200, 125, 200, 150, 110, 150, 300, 140, 150, 
120, 110, 140, 101, 150, 150, 130, 150, 120, 150, 130, 120, 120, 
125, 120, 110, 80, 110, 125, 110, 150, 105, 110, 125, 105, 105, 
150, 150, 150, 105, 111, 150, 110, 150, 115, 200, 125, 150, 500, 
110, 175, 115, 225, 115, 200, 150, 150, 110, 200, 400, 150, 125, 
150, 150, 125, 110, 35, 110, 70, 120, 150, 175, 120, 105, 120, 
130, 150, 120, 400, 110, 105, 105, 120, 120, 120, 150, 115, 180, 
160, 150, 115, 110, 200, 90, 150, 112, 200, 150, 90, 150, 155, 
115, 200, 120, 115, 120, 300, 180, 250, 600, 150, 220, 150, 250, 
200, 125, 300, 150, 200, 125, 85, 175, 175, 200, 50, 130, 150, 
200, 150, 120, 110, 200, 120, 150, 130, 150, 120, 70, 150, 150, 
120, 75, 130, 120, 150, 90, 150, 150, 130, 110, 120, 120, 90, 
120, 130, 115, 130, 150, 120, 130, 115, 170, 500, 130, 114, 200, 
115, 125, 120, 105, 110, 110, 105, 125, 105, 110, 110, 105, 120, 
120, 120, 125, 150, 130, 105, 105, 103, 120, 115, 110, 200, 105, 
105, 105, 120, 150, 125, 140, 110, 150, 110, 150, 100, 110, 200, 
200, 105, 300, 200, 500, 130, 200, 120, 130, 105, 105, 90, 115, 
105, 150, 150, 110, 110, 80, 140, 130, 200, 150, 150, 120, 170, 
140, 180, 130, 130, 170, 130, 120, 120, 120, 120, 110, 120, 120, 
150, 110, 200, 105, 125, 98, 85, 125, 200, 150, 130, 150, 150, 
120, 110, 100, 300, 90, 110, 110, 105, 200, 150, 98, 105, 120, 
110, 120, 120, 120, 180, 110, 105, 95, 105, 98, 200, 85, 120, 
95, 110, 125, 125, 102, 105, 110, 125, 103, 120, 120, 120, 110,  
105, 120, 120, 150, 150, 120, 110, 125, 105, 125, 200, 130, 115, 
125, 120, 90, 120, 200, 150, 200, 150, 120, 115, 150, 150, 200, 
150, 200, 150, 150, 120, 125, 200, 200, 110, 200, 120, 90, 120, 
200, 95, 95, 110, 95, 110, 140, 110, 150, 150, 150, 110, 120, 
120, 110, 120, 75, 110, 150, 110, 150, 120, 150, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 150, 90, 120, 95, 140, 150, 150, 90, 200, 130, 90, 
110, 75, 110, 150, 140, 150, 115, 110, 120, 120, 130, 115, 110, 
110, 120, 110, 110, 200, 150, 120, 110, 300, 110, 120, 130, 190, 
110, 105, 120, 200, 105, 200, 160, 115, 120, 120, 110, 120, 110, 
150, 120, 120, 125, 120, 170, 110, 105, 150, 150, 110, 120, 110, 
200, 115, 90, 110, 140, 110, 102, 200, 200, 110, 115, 120, 105, 
120, 100, 300, 120, 140, 105, 130, 140, 200, 110, 300, 85, 125, 
120, 90, 140, 90, 130, 125, 110, 140, 130, 170, 130, 120, 80, 
120, 110, 110, 120, 200, 600, 120, 135, 140, 200, 150, 110, 120, 
110, 85, 85, 90, 90, 130, 90, 80, 115, 110, 110, 110, 200, 120, 
120, 115, 120, 120, 300, 125, 130, 120, 70, 140, 200, 95, 120, 
200, 110, 140, 150, 100, 200, 200, 95, 180, 150, 150, 120, 150, 
105, 150, 110, 110, 150, 140, 140, 140, 200, 115, 120, 105, 120, 
105, 110, 150, 120, 101, 140, 140, 140, 150, 140, 110, 105, 130, 
110, 150, 130, 135, 150, 150, 105, 120, 200, 120, 140, 110, 140, 
110, 110, 150, 110, 160, 150, 120, 120, 100, 150, 150, 120, 120, 
300, 90, 105, 150, 200, 150, 200, 110, 200, 105, 200, 150, 190, 
130, 140, 130, 135, 135, 180, 150, 200, 150, 150, 150, 140, 140, 
140, 140, 130, 150, 140, 160, 200, 200, 150, 120, 120, 130, 140, 
125, 105, 110, 120, 140, 135, 150, 110, 110, 150, 130, 140, 140, 
170, 140, 120, 160, 160, 180, 150, 125, 130, 115, 140, 130, 105, 
110, 160, 140, 140, 120, 105, 130, 115, 150, 150, 110, 140, 190, 
120, 140, 130, 150, 150, 115, 125, 110, 120, 90, 120, 200, 110, 
120, 105, 130, 150, 65, 110, 110, 110, 120, 150, 150, 200, 105, 
120, 110, 110, 120, 110, 101, 105, 105, 110, 110, 150, 120, 150, 
120, 200, 200, 110, 125, 180, 120, 120, 150, 200, 110, 200, 80, 
80, 200, 200, 100, 150, 100, 110, 110, 120, 110, 145, 110, 200, 
90, 120, 200, 200, 130, 120, 110, 150, 200, 110, 100, 140, 160, 
105, 125, 150, 200, 150, 120, 140, 140, 107, 110, 150, 500, 150, 
150, 120, 110, 110, 130, 200, 110, 110, 200, 120, 400, 125, 300, 
110, 200, 125, 150, 150, 110, 110, 125, 200, 120, 150, 110, 200, 
135, 120, 150, 150, 110, 130, 90, 150, 120, 140, 130, 110, 175, 
90, 200, 105, 150, 600, 120, 200, 150, 120, 200, 150, 120, 105, 
180, 130, 150, 120, 500, 115, 105, 120, 125, 450, 200, 110, 105, 
150, 150, 110, 120, 160, 200, 175, 600, 150, 150, 95, 115, 200, 
125, 200, 125, 105, 200, 120, 140, 140, 120, 130, 95, 120, 105, 
125, 120, 115, 130, 150, 90, 120, 200, 110, 120, 200, 105, 300, 
150, 110, 120, 80, 140, 130, 120, 150, 80, 200, 90, 150, 90, 
115, 130, 102, 130, 130, 150, 110, 110, 150, 400, 500, 95, 125, 
120, 120, 250, 115, 110, 125, 130, 400, 150, 150, 125, 150, 160, 
110, 150, 160, 250, 120, 120, 200, 120, 120, 120, 130, 120, 130, 
150, 150, 200, 115, 105, 105, 150, 110, 150, 150, 110, 120, 300, 
125, 200, 90, 250, 90, 110, 500, 160, 200, 600, 115, 120, 115, 
100, 90, 200, 200, 108, 400, 150, 500, 100, 120, 150, 200, 105, 
120, 115, 110, 140, 110, 120, 200, 94, 200, 120, 150, 110, 90, 
150, 120, 110, 120, 150, 200, 120, 120, 110, 120, 110, 120, 150, 
120, 200, 120, 200, 150, 200, 110, 130, 150, 150, 150, 200, 150, 
110, 150, 75, 150, 120, 300, 120, 130, 120, 200, 140, 120, 130, 
110, 150, 130, 110, 200, 150, 200, 120, 120, 140, 110, 140, 90, 
101, 110, 150, 150, 130, 105, 125, 140, 115, 200, 95, 200, 105, 
150, 120, 110, 90, 115, 120, 115, 95, 95, 95, 170, 180, 110, 
150, 150, 150, 102, 600, 190, 170, 110, 125, 90, 300, 102, 130, 
130, 130, 150, 120, 150, 150, 150, 200, 75, 106, 50, 110, 150, 
150, 150, 130, 600, 130, 250, 200, 120, 80, 150, 110, 120, 120, 
150, 130, 140, 130, 140, 200, 110, 50, 500, 105, 90, 120, 150, 
200, 150, 120, 120, 125, 150, 120, 110, 120, 110, 300, 200, 300, 
150, 200, 130, 300, 150, 130, 90, 120, 120, 150, 160, 130, 90, 
200, 110, 200, 110, 150, 130, 150, 150, 140, 160, 130, 170, 165, 
120, 140, 130, 110, 140, 150, 200, 95, 150, 90, 120, 120, 120, 
95, 120, 120, 120, 150, 200, 105, 160, 150, 130, 110, 130, 110, 
125, 175, 110, 120, 95, 160, 120, 130, 120, 400, 120, 200, 150, 
150, 120, 75, 85, 90, 105, 110, 200, 125, 110, 110, 120, 500, 
120, 200, 180, 125, 120, 110, 105, 95, 110, 150, 110, 110, 110, 
150, 90, 150, 125, 125, 150, 150, 150, 150, 90, 120, 110, 130, 
125, 160, 200, 135, 120, 120, 90, 110, 150, 120, 120, 110, 120, 
120, 120, 200, 200, 130, 150, 150, 150, 160, 120, 120, 200, 130, 
250, 300, 110, 180, 250, 600, 115, 115, 600, 130, 120, 200, 130, 
700, 110, 105, 105, 400, 108, 105, 130, 125, 120, 200, 120, 600, 
120, 150, 220, 130, 135, 140, 145, 140, 150, 120, 200, 130, 600, 
125, 130, 130, 130, 115, 500, 135, 130, 170, 130, 125, 130, 140, 
150, 110, 135, 120, 140, 150, 140, 150, 100, 150, 200, 150, 200, 
100, 150, 150, 200, 200, 110, 200, 150, 101, 150, 300, 120, 600, 
400, 150, 250, 120, 130, 170, 135, 125, 160, 300, 190, 180, 150, 
105, 130, 105, 108, 120, 145, 130, 140, 120, 130, 150, 130, 130, 
170, 140, 150, 160, 105, 102, 200, 110, 115, 185, 130, 120, 110, 
125, 125, 125, 130, 180, 500, 600, 120, 115, 125, 125, 125, 120, 
110, 175, 250, 500, 130, 150, 160, 170, 170, 125, 130, 140, 200, 
115, 80, 150, 130, 120, 120, 200, 200, 600, 130, 150, 200, 110, 
125, 250, 200, 200, 125, 110, 115, 100, 130, 550, 110, 120, 130, 
125, 130, 122, 500, 120, 125, 125, 145, 130, 130, 150, 130, 150, 
150, 125, 140, 130, 123, 130, 150, 120, 130, 120, 115, 130, 125, 
140, 140, 120, 160, 150, 140, 200, 200, 150, 200, 105, 115, 200, 
140, 130, 400, 105, 115, 175, 300, 120, 105, 105, 105, 200, 120, 
105, 110, 120, 115, 130, 105, 150, 110, 130, 140, 150, 120, 120, 
200, 150, 130, 110, 120, 200, 120, 120, 160, 110, 120, 130, 150, 
140, 105, 150, 130, 140, 115, 120, 120, 110, 200, 120, 120, 200, 
130, 200, 150, 100, 125, 150, 175, 150, 120, 120, 120, 120, 90, 
150, 150, 85, 120, 200, 500, 150, 120, 150, 90, 120, 150, 105, 
120, 150, 110, 130, 110, 97, 400, 175, 125, 120, 150, 150, 140, 
200, 140, 200, 125, 150, 85, 150, 110, 140, 110, 140, 150, 140
)
```

Comment: "can someone please help me out.": potential helpers are more likely to be motivated to assist if you had accepted any answer to any of your previous question.  Accepting an answer not only shows appreciation for the help given but also assists others with similar questions in the past.

Comment: And please don't give us a test dataset that is incompatible with your code.  help yourself by helping us to help you and give us a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I'm really sorry but since I'm new I was upvoting instead of accepting. Doing it rn

Comment: The example that I have given is the data for wave18 in the loop where I am getting an error. `df$jk[df$wave==18]`